# Retrieving Fitbit heart rate data

Tags: python, fitbit

I've been using the [Fitbit Python package](https://python-fitbit.readthedocs.org) to analyse my data. When I look at my exercise data it seems to work really well:

```
fitbit_stats = authd_client._COLLECTION_RESOURCE('activities', date='2015-09-16')
```

However, when I try to get my heart rate data, it runs, but doesn't return anything except 0s:

```
fitbit_stats = authd_client._COLLECTION_RESOURCE('heart', date='2015-09-16')
print fitbit_stats
```

> {'heart': [], 'average': [{'tracker': 'Resting Heart Rate',
>   'heartRate': 0}, {'tracker': 'Normal Heart Rate', 'heartRate': 0},
>   {'tracker': 'Exertive Heart Rate', 'heartRate': 0}]}

Does anyone know why I'm not returning any data here?

Comment: FWIW, I suspect it's a bug. I registered on dev.fitbit.com, cloned the latest python-fitbit repo, gathered my OAuth2 credentials, created a fitbit.Fitbit instance with oauth2=True, and could gather everything I tested except heart rate. I didn't dig further, but was able to get the data using the API tester here: https://www.connect2.me/fitbit/fitbit-heart

Answer (score 5):

The following will work but I'm not sure this is what you are looking for

```
fitbit_stats = authd_client._COLLECTION_RESOURCE('activities/heart', date='2016-08-11')
print fitbit_stats
```

I'm guessing you want the intraday date (like me)

According to https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/heart-rate/#get-heart-rate-intraday-time-series

> Access to the Intraday Time Series for personal use (accessing your
>   own data) is available through the "Personal" App Type.
>
> Access to the Intraday Time Series for all other uses is currently
>   granted on a case-by-case basis. ...

I've added a custom function to the fitbit api package:

```
def get_heartrate_intraday(self, date="today", end_date="1d", detail_level="1sec", user_id=None):
    uri = "{0}/{1}/user/-/activities/heart/date/{date}/{end_date}/{detail_level}.json"

    date = self._get_date_string(date)
    end_date = self._get_date_string(end_date)

    url = uri.format(
        *self._get_common_args(user_id=user_id),
        date=date,
        end_date=end_date,
        detail_level=detail_level
    )
    return self.make_request(url)
```

The data this will return looks like:

```
'activities-heart-intraday': {
    'dataset': [
        {'time': '00:00:00', 'value': 66},
        {'time': '00:00:10', 'value': 67},
        {'time': '00:00:25', 'value': 67},
        {'time': '00:00:40', 'value': 67},

        {'time': '23:57:40', 'value': 84},
        {'time': '23:58:40', 'value': 85},
        {'time': '23:58:50', 'value': 80}
    ],
    'datasetInterval': 1,
    'datasetType': 'second'
}
```